# How to setup custom permissions exactly for an app in Django?

Tags: django, django-permissions

In admin panel we can see a list of permissions look like this

`auth | user | add user`

which are suit to template

`<app> | <model> | <event> <model>`

What if I don't have models and i just want to have two permissions on the whole app `change` and `view`? So I can write some custom instructions on what users with the appropriate permission can do.

Comment: default permissions of Django are just instances affected to your user instance or groups. You may at the same time create your own and add them to any model.

Comment: @Lemayzeur can you share more details? I don't see where in code to initialize new permissions. Also i'd like to not to create a new model in my app for permissions. Is that a good idea to add it in auth permission model?